# Using show() and hide() in Konva for Groups

Tags: konvajs

I created a Konva Group and added several objects to it. When I invoke `hide()` on the group and then `layer.draw()` to refresh the canvas, the object is still showing. What am I doing wrong?

(Konva 1.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented requirement that, for a child object in a group, you must set the visible property to `inherit` for the child to respect the parent's visibility field.

```
var g = new Konva.Group();
var c = new Konva.Circle({
    radius : 5,
    visible : 'inherit'
});
g.add(c);
```

Comment: You don't need such special requirement. http://jsbin.com/retahawexi/edit?js,output

Comment: Interesting, I will try to see why it seemed like I did need it.

Comment: @Mikeb - if this solution worked please can you mark as the correct answer.